# ksqlDB: Joining tables/streams with nested structure(not flattened)

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I got two different topics with their own schema in avro format, X and Y. Both of these topics have a lot of fields.
I want to create a table-stream join relation between them and output it to another topic in the following format:

```
{
   id, // the id used to join them
   x_name : X,
   y_name: Y
}
```

With other words, I want to join these two with each source nested.
I am able to join them in a normal way, however all fields are flattened out.
Can this be achieved with KsqlDB? I've tried to find a good way of doing this without success.

EDIT:

Adding more information and example.
Say I have two topics with this type of data.

product_supply

```
{
  "product_id": 1,
  "name": "name",
  "stock": 11
  "price": "141",
  "storage_ids": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

product_information

```
{
  "product_id": 1,
  "description": "151",
  "manufacturer": "ABC"
  "Vendor_id": "5"
}
```

I'd like to use KsqlDB to join these tables in a unflattened manner and publish to a topic, like this:

```
{
  "product_id": 1,
  "product_information": {
      "product_id": 1,
      "description": "151",
      "manufacturer": "ABC"
      "Vendor_id": "5"
  }
  "product_supply": {
      "product_id": 1,
      "name": "name",
      "stock": 11
      "price": "141",
      "storage_ids": [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

I've added schema for each topic and wish if possible, to use the schemas without having to explicitly define each field in ksql.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you edit your question to include an example of the two message types that you're trying to join please?

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks! I've added an example to demonstrate my intention. I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good guide here on [working with structured data in ksqlDB](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/query-structured-data/). Based on this I was able to get this to work:

- Create sample data

  ```sql
  CREATE STREAM PRODUCT_SUPPLY (PRODUCT_ID INT, NAME VARCHAR, STOCK INT, PRICE INT, STORAGE_IDS ARRAY<INT>) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='PRODUCT_SUPPLY', REPLICAS=1,PARTITIONS=6,VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
  CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_INFORMATION (PRODUCT_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR, MANUFACTURER VARCHAR, VENDOR_ID INT) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='PRODUCT_INFO', REPLICAS=1,PARTITIONS=6,VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
  INSERT INTO PRODUCT_SUPPLY VALUES(1,'NAME',11,141,ARRAY[1,2,3]);
  INSERT INTO PRODUCT_INFORMATION values (1,'151','abc',5);
  ```
- Query the data

  ```sql
  SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';

  SELECT PS.PRODUCT_ID AS PRODUCT_ID,
        STRUCT(NAME        := PS.NAME,
                STOCK       := PS.STOCK,
                PRICE       := PS.PRICE,
                STORAGE_IDS := PS.STORAGE_IDS) AS PRODUCT_SUPPLY,
        STRUCT(DESCRIPTION  := PI.DESCRIPTION,
                MANUFACTURER := PI.MANUFACTURER,
                VENDOR_ID    := PI.VENDOR_ID) AS PRODUCT_INFORMATION
    FROM PRODUCT_SUPPLY PS
        LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_INFORMATION PI
        ON PS.PRODUCT_ID=PI.PRODUCT_ID
  EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 1;
  ```

  ```
  +-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
  |PRODUCT_ID               |PRODUCT_SUPPLY           |PRODUCT_INFORMATION      |
  +-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
  |1                        |{NAME=NAME, STOCK=11, PRI|{DESCRIPTION=151, MANUFAC|
  |                         |CE=141, STORAGE_IDS=[1, 2|TURER=abc, VENDOR_ID=5}  |
  |                         |, 3]}                    |                         |
  Limit Reached
  Query terminated
  ```

Comment: Can you please let me know why I am getting below error.

Caused by: line 1:40: mismatched input ':' expecting {',', ')'}
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException

error caused at  ":="

Comment: @PradipB please start a new question with full details of how to reproduce your issue. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I posted new question here can you please guide me on it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919311/ksqldb-joining-streams-to-nested-structure-and-sink-to-postgresql

Comment: How can I do something similar but when the topic structure is AVRO with a format similar to:
`{
 "op": "u",
 "source": {
  ...
 },
 "ts_ms" : "...",
 "before" : {
  "field1" : "oldvalue1",
  "field2" : "oldvalue2"
 },
 "after" : {
  "field1" : "newvalue1",
  "field2" : "newvalue2"
 }
}`