# ksqlDB: Joining streams to nested structure and Sink to postgresql

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

We have setup source connector (`io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector`) on postgersql db which will listen to 3 tables and forward data changes to Kafka topic.

And created streams for this 3 topics. Below are list of streams running fine and listening to tables.

Stream "Stream_Project" created from topic `projects`

```
+-----------+-------------+
|ProjectId  |ProjectName  |
+-------------------------+
|1          |Project 1    |
|2          |Project 2    |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Stream "Stream_Skill" data created from topic `skills`

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|SkillId    |ProjectId    |SkillName    |Proficiency  |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|1          |1            |Skill 101    |L1           |
|2          |1            |Skill 102    |L2           |
|3          |2            |Skill 201    |L1           |
|4          |2            |Skill 202    |L2           |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Stream "Stream_Tech" data created from topic `techs`

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|TechId     |ProjectId    |TechName     |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|1          |1            |Tech 101     |
|2          |1            |Tech 102     |
|3          |2            |Tech 201     |
|4          |2            |Tech 202     |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Now I am trying to join all the stream to get result as below in new stream/table which I can `Sink` to another PostgresSql db. But I am not sure how I can get result as below from joining all the 3 stream data.

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|ProjectId  |ProjectName  |Skills                                                                                      |Techs                                             |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|1          |Project 1    |[{"SkillName":"Skill 101","Proficiency":"L1"},{"SkillName":"Skill 102","Proficiency":"L2"}] |[{"TechName":"Tech 101"},{"TechName":"Tech 102"}] |
|2          |Project 2    |[{"SkillName":"Skill 201","Proficiency":"L1"},{"SkillName":"Skill 202","Proficiency":"L2"}] |[{"TechName":"Tech 201"},{"TechName":"Tech 202"}] |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Can anyone guide me or provide way to generate output as above in `ksqlDB`
Thanks